# Print selected attributes form json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I loaded a json file into a variable. Now i need to print some attributes from that variable(json object). I could able to access them individually,but I could not able to irritate and save them.

```
var companyList = (function() {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "/company_list.json",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
console.log(companyList.comp001.title); // This works 

let htmlString = "";

for (i = 0; i <480; i++) {
htmlString += "<p>" + companyList.comp[i].title + " </P>";
};     // I could not able to save them in htmlstring
```

my json file looks some thing like this. I need to print title of every company

```
{
"comp001": {
  "title": "AachenMünchener",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp002": {
  "title": "ADAC",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp003": {
  "title": "ADLER",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp004": {
  "title": "ADVOCARD",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},}
```

Comment: if you are using ajax. its impossible to assign the variable...please use promised callback `.then()` instead..http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way will be to loop over the object keys and get the `title` value for each object using `Object.keys(companyList)`:

```js
var companyList = {
"comp001": {
  "title": "AachenMünchener",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp002": {
  "title": "ADAC",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp003": {
  "title": "ADLER",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp004": {
  "title": "ADVOCARD",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
}};

let htmlString = "";

Object.keys(companyList).forEach(function(key){
  htmlString += "<p>" + companyList[key].title; + " </P>";
});
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = htmlString;
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that :

```
for (i = 0; i <480; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + companyList.comp[i].title + " </P>";
}
```

will search `companyList.comp[i]` which doesn't exists since `companyList` doesn't contain any array `comp` so `comp[i]` is not possible. You can do

```
companyList["comp" + i].title
```

for it to work.

But it's not all, your `for` work for 480 company only, if you have less, you'll get many undefined in `htmlString`, if you have more you'll lose some in the way

```js
companyList = {
"comp001": {
  "title": "AachenMünchener",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp002": {
  "title": "ADAC",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp003": {
  "title": "ADLER",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},
"comp004": {
  "title": "ADVOCARD",
  "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i",
  "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
},}

let htmlString = ""
for (let company in companyList) {
  htmlString += "<p>" + companyList[company].title + "</p>";
}; 

console.log(htmlString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get they keys, and then reduce the object to build the final html with all titles.

```js
var companyList = {
  "comp001": {
    "title": "AachenMünchener",
    "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i",
    "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de001.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
  },
  "comp002": {
    "title": "ADAC",
    "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i",
    "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de002.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
  },
  "comp003": {
    "title": "ADLER",
    "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i",
    "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de003.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
  },
  "comp004": {
    "title": "ADVOCARD",
    "img": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i",
    "imgsrcset": "/company-logos/logos1x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 1x, /company-logos/logos2x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 2x, /company-logos/logos3x/de004.png?ver=gz30i 3x"
  }
};


const htmlString = Object.keys(companyList).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  return acc + "<p>" + companyList[key].title + " </p>";
}, "");
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = htmlString;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

In your code, you have an object, where values are accessed using the properties. But you treated it as an array, where items are accessed by the index. This fundamental wrong assumption failing your code.